# counting number of directories in a specific directory

Tags: linux, bash

How to count the number of folders in a specific directory. I am using the following command, but it always provides an extra one.

```
find /directory/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -print| wc -l
```

For example, if I have 3 folders, this command provides 4. If it contains 5 folders, the command provides 6. Why is that?

Comment: The additional 1 count is there due the the current directory '.' , which is also taken into account by 'find'.

Answer (score 130):

`find` is also printing the directory itself:

```
$ find .vim/ -maxdepth 1 -type d
.vim/
.vim/indent
.vim/colors
.vim/doc
.vim/after
.vim/autoload
.vim/compiler
.vim/plugin
.vim/syntax
.vim/ftplugin
.vim/bundle
.vim/ftdetect
```

You can instead test the directory's children and do not descend into them at all:

```
$ find .vim/* -maxdepth 0 -type d
.vim/after
.vim/autoload
.vim/bundle
.vim/colors
.vim/compiler
.vim/doc
.vim/ftdetect
.vim/ftplugin
.vim/indent
.vim/plugin
.vim/syntax

$ find .vim/* -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l
11
$ find .vim/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
12
```

You can also use `ls`:

```
$ ls -l .vim | grep -c ^d
11


$ ls -l .vim
total 52
drwxrwxr-x  3 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 after
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 autoload
drwxrwxr-x 13 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 bundle
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 colors
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 compiler
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 anossovp anossovp   48 Aug 29  2012 filetype.vim
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 ftdetect
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 ftplugin
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 indent
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 plugin
-rw-rw-r--  1 anossovp anossovp 2505 Aug 29  2012 README.rst
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 syntax

$ ls -l .vim | grep ^d
drwxrwxr-x  3 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 after
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 autoload
drwxrwxr-x 13 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 bundle
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 colors
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 compiler
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 doc
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 ftdetect
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 ftplugin
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 indent
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 plugin
drwxrwxr-x  2 anossovp anossovp 4096 Aug 29  2012 syntax
```

Comment: Nice! How would you do this `$ ls -l .vim` with PHP? Or how to get only the total, without the list. I mean, in this case get only `52`?

Comment: Hah. I love how the argument against PowerShell is that BASH is easier in every way... want to see the POSH command to do this? `(ls).Count`

Comment: @Pathros Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php) with flag GLOB_ONLYDIR and count() the result.

Comment: `ls -l | grep -c ^d` is dead simple and works. @Pathros there is a probably a better way in PHP, but worst case in PHP you can always use shell_exec() function to execute command line and return results to a string. 

i.e. 
`$dirCount = shell_exec('ls -l | grep -c ^d');`

Answer (score 94):

Get a count of only the directories in the current directory

`echo */ | wc`

you will get out put like `1     309    4594`

`2nd digit` represents no. of directories.

or

`tree -L 1 | tail -1`

Comment: This fails if there are spaces in the dir names, unfortunately.

Comment: `zsh: no matches found: */` needs nullglob

Comment: @AnnevanRossum Do you have `echo` . type `which echo`

Comment: The first one can be further improved a bit: `echo */ | wc -w`

Comment: Nota that this will count 1 if there are no directories instead of 0.

Comment: According to [SC2035](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2035) - use ./* so names with dashes won't become options: `echo ./* | wc -w`

Answer (score 45):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

For find `-mindepth` means total number recusive in directories

`-maxdepth` means total number recusive in directories

`-type d` means directory

And for `wc -l` means count the lines of the input

Comment: Can you explain your answer please (inside your answer) ?

Comment: -mindepth means total number recusive in directories,-maxdepth means total number recusive in directories, -type d means directory, and wc -l means line count from given directory listing

Comment: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l` will give you a lot of spaces between the number, for example:  
`        2    `  
you can prevent it by using this:  
```dir_count=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l | xargs`;
echo $dir_count # will print just 2
```
and could be useful for conditions, like:
`if (( $dir_count > 1 )); then echo "Yaa"; fi # will print "Yaa"`

Answer (score 33):

If you only have directories in the folder and no files this does it:

```
ls | wc -l
```

Comment: This gets also files, but the question was about folders / directories.

Comment: I think this doesn't get hidden files, but works great to just get the number of objects in a directory.

Comment: I think you can do `ls -a | wc -l` to get hidden stuff in the count

Answer (score 15):

Run `stat -c %h folder` and subtract 2 from the result.  This employs only a single subprocess as opposed to the 2 (or even 3) required by most of the other solutions here (typically `find` or `ls` plus `wc`).

Using sh/bash:

> echo $((`stat -c %h folder` - 2))   # 'echo' is a shell builtin

Using csh/tcsh:

> @ cnt = `stat -c %h folder` - 2; echo $cnt   # 'echo' is a shell builtin

**Explanation**: `stat -c %h folder` prints the number of hardlinks to *folder*, and each subfolder under *folder* contains a ../ entry which is a hardlink back to *folder*.  You must subtract 2 because there are two additional hardlinks in the count:

1. *folder*'s own self-referential ./ entry, and
2. *folder*'s parent's link to *folder*

Comment: Related to this question: [Why does a new directory have a hard link count of 2 before anything is added to it?
](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101515) It explains why this is an excellent answer. Unfortunately, this did not receive enough attention! While it is a good answer, the outcome of it depends unfortunately on the filesystem, but for most common filesystems, this will work.

Answer (score 13):

Best way to navigate to your drive and simply execute

```
ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l
```

and to Find all folders in total, including subdirectories?

```
find /mount/point -type d | wc -l
```

...or find all folders in the root directory (not including subdirectories)?

```
find /mount/point -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

Cheers!

Comment: Note that the previous ls `-lR` ignore the dot prefixed directory while `find -type d`  count them.So the count given by the first command is wrong if you have dot prefixed directories (example you have .git subdirectory!). You cannot simply use  `-lRa` because you get also for each directory a `.` and `..` entry. It applies also to the answer of @Pavel Anossov

Answer (score 9):

No of directory we can find using below command

`ls -l | grep "^d" | wc -l`

Comment: Just `ls -l | grep ^d | wc -l` will do, there is no need to use `"` here

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest is

```
  ls -ld images/* | wc -l
```

where `images` is your target directory. The -d flag limits to directories, and the -l flag will perform a per-line listing, compatible with the very familiar `wc -l` for line count.

Comment: Also returns result +1

Comment: According to `man ls`, `-d` does: "list directories themselves, not their contents", that is, if you run `ls /tmp`, you'll get what is in `/tmp`, and if you run `ls -d /tmp` you just get `/tmp`. The `-d` switch does not filter directories, as was asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Some useful examples:

count files in current dir

```
/bin/ls -lA  | egrep -c '^-'
```

count dirs in current dir

```
/bin/ls -lA  | egrep -c '^d'
```

count files and dirs in current dir

```
/bin/ls -lA  | egrep -c '^-|^d'
```

count files and dirs in in one subdirectory

```
/bin/ls -lA  subdir_name/ | egrep -c '^-|^d'
```

I have noticed a strange thing (at least in my case) :

> When I have tried with `ls` instead `/bin/ls`
>   the `-A` parameter `do not list implied . and ..` NOT WORK as espected. When I use
>   `ls` that show ./ and ../ So that result wrong count. SOLUTION : `/bin/ls` instead `ls`

Answer (score 6):

**To get the number of directories - navigate
go to the directory and execute**

```
 ls -l | grep -c ^d
```

Answer (score 4):

A pure bash solution:

```
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=( /path/to/directory/*/ )
echo "There are ${#dirs[@]} (non-hidden) directories"
```

If you also want to count the hidden directories:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
dirs=( /path/to/directory/*/ )
echo "There are ${#dirs[@]} directories (including hidden ones)"
```

Note that this will also count links to directories. If you don't want that, it's a bit more difficult with this method.

---

Using `find`:

```
find /path/to/directory -type d \! -name . -prune -exec printf x \; | wc -c
```

The trick is to output an `x` to stdout each time a directory is found, and then use `wc` to count the number of characters. This will count the number of all directories (including hidden ones), excluding links.

---

The methods presented here are all safe wrt to funny characters that can appear in file names (spaces, newlines, glob characters, etc.).

Comment: This is the best solution presented in this question and will work always!

Answer (score 4):

The best answer to what you want is

```
echo `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l`-1 | bc
```

this subtracts one to remove the unwanted '.' directory that find lists (as patel deven mentioned above).

If you want to count subfolders recursively, then just leave off the maxdepth option, so

```
echo `find . -type d | wc -l`-1 | bc
```

PS If you find command substitution ugly, subtracting one can be done as a pure stream using `sed` and `bc`.

Subtracting one from count:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l | sed 's/$/-1\n/' | bc
```

or, adding count to minus one:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l | sed 's/^/-1+/' | bc
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `zsh`:

```
a=(*(/N)); echo ${#a}
```

The `N` is a nullglob, `/` makes it match directories, `#` counts. It will neatly cope with spaces in directory names as well as returning `0` if there are no directories.

Answer (score 0):

Count all files and subfolders, windows style:

```
dir=/YOUR/PATH;f=$(find $dir -type f | wc -l); d=$(find $dir -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l); echo "$f Files, $d Folders"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions, then try:

```
ls -c | grep "^d" | wc -l
```

Comment: Would you like to add some explanation to your code-only answer? It would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service. Also, have a look here to improve appearance: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count folders that have similar names like folder01,folder02,folder03, etc then you can do

```
ls -l | grep ^d | grep -c folder
```

Answer (score -2):

Best way to do it:

```
ls -la | grep -v total | wc -l
```

This gives you the perfect count.

Comment: You mean that's the worse way to do it! besides, this doesn't count the number of _directories._ And what if there's a directory name that contains the string `total`? your method is broken `:(`. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!